# Waiting for Page to Load before accepting alert Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to do some basic web crawling and would like to be able to accept (or dismiss) any alert on screen so I can access page elements. Earlier, I was managing this by doing an expected wait for an alert.

```
private void handleAlert(){
    try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
        Logger.log("Accepting alert~!~~~~!!!");
        }catch(NoAlertPresentException e){
            // Do nothing :D
        }catch(UnhandledAlertException e){
                Logger.writeError("An alert was not handled!");
        }catch(TimeoutException e){
            Logger.writeError("There was a timeout occurring handling alert");
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a problem with this if a page is not loaded in the first 2 seconds but then loads afterwards (My page load timeout was 15 seconds). In this case, there is an alert present but, I will no longer try to dismiss/accept this.

To fix this, I decided to write a bit of code to wait until the page loads before trying to handle the alert. The code is below:

```
    /**
     * Load an Url in the chrome browser via Selenium driver
     * @param url: The web address to be crawled
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public boolean loadUrl(String url) throws InterruptedException{
        try{
            driver.get(url);
            waitTillPageLoads();
            handleAlert();
            return true;
        }catch(TimeoutException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.writeError("There was a timeout for the url: "+url);
            return false;
        }
    } 

    /**
     * Use webdriver expected conditions override to wait until
     * DOM state is completed
     */
    private void waitTillPageLoads(){
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
            {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
                {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                }
            };
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(expectation);
    }
```

Buuuuut, If I do this, I get an AlertNotHandledException as specified by the summarized stack trace below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open
    Session ID: 876c48f2d94d10fe30984ab94f32884e
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:164)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
        at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver$1.apply(TestChromeDriver.java:349)
        at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver$1.apply(TestChromeDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
        at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.waitTillPageLoads(TestChromeDriver.java:353)
        at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.loadUrl(TestChromeDriver.java:364)
        at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.crawl(TestChromeDriver.java:308)
        at src.com.chrome.TestChromeDriver.main(TestChromeDriver.java:132)
```

So, how do I wait until the page is loaded AND THEN try to handle a javascript alert IF it exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what you're doing, and *really* have to bypass all JavaScript alerts and dialogs regardless of the consequences, you could always [follow this advice](http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/):

`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.alert = function() {}; window.prompt = function() {return null}; window.confirm = function() {return true}");`

You would need to run that after **every** page load, but it's certainly cleaner than trying to deal with unpredictable, variable behaviour.

*(If you want to trial it, open up your browser's developer tools, paste the scriptlet into the JS console, then verify that `alert('hi');` does nothing.)*

Comment: I just tried this (by essentially replacing my handleAlert function with your snippet), and it returns an UnhandledAlertException xD. I found that funny because that's exactly what this should be avoiding hahaha.

Comment: I can't see what page you're loading, and can't tell where these alerts are supposed to occur, but if you're waiting until the page loads before executing it, that may be too late. You should run it as soon as possible after you've requested the page to minimise the chance of any alerts/dialogs showing.

Comment: I know this is a very old question but I recall that this did work. So I just accepted the answer.